# Sealed Class in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, case-class, traits

Below is my code snippet:

```
sealed abstract class Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
case class Number(num: Double) extends Expr
case class UnOp(operator: String, arg: Expr) extends Expr
case class BinOp(operator: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

object CaseClassTest extends App {
    def simplifyExp(xs: Expr): Expr = xs match {
      case UnOp("-",UnOp("-", x)) => x
      case BinOp("+",x,Number(0)) => x
      case BinOp("*",x,Number(1)) => x
    }

    def describe(e: Expr): String = e match {
      case Number(_) => "Number"
      case Var(_) => "Var"
    } 
}
```

Now what is happening in describe method I am getting a warning stating that "**match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following inputs: BinOp(_, _, *), UnOp(*, _)**". It looks perfectly for me as I am not considering other test cases like BinOp, UnOp. Perfect

But my question why the same warning is not coming for the **def simplifyExp(xs: Expr): Expr** ? Is there something which I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In case of `simplifyExp`, you use extractor composition and I think that the compiler is not smart enough to detect the problem.

Obvisously, the following code fails at runtime with a `MatchError`

```
CaseClassTest.simplifyExp(Var("toto"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler shows a genuine warning, as `simplifyExp` cannot handle all arguments of type `Expr`. For example on doing:

```
scala> simplifyExp(new Var("as"))
scala.MatchError: Var(as) (of class Var)
        at .simplifyExp(<console>:22)
        at .<init>(<console>:24)...
```

Similarly it cannot handle arguments of type `BinOp(_, _, _)` i.e. BinOp taking any String, any left Expr, right Expr.

About the second function, change the order of declaration and it displays warning for `describe` also:

```
scala> object CaseClassTest extends App {
    def describe(e: Expr): String = e match {
      case Number(_) => "Number"
      case Var(_) => "Var"
    }

    def simplifyExp(xs: Expr): Expr = xs match {
      case UnOp("-",UnOp("-", x)) => x
      case BinOp("+",x,Number(0)) => x
      case BinOp("*",x,Number(1)) => x
    }

}
<console>:23: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: BinOp(_, _, _), UnOp(_, _)
           def describe(e: Expr): String = e match {
                                           ^
defined module CaseClassTest
```

If you correct `describe` in above case, then it will display for `simplifyExpr` also.

Comment: Hey Jatin, I think you misunderstood my question. My question was why the function simplifyExp is not showing the warning when it is supposed to do. Anyway I tried your second solution i.e. changing the order (Move describe on top of simplifyExp) and the correct the describe function. But still simplifyExp is not showing any error?